# Sign extending / extracting nibbles

Tags: assembly

I'm a beginner in Assembly, and I wrote a very simple program that would show a MessageBox in Windows 7 using the Win32 API. I wanted to modify this so that the text in the MessageBox was the current EIP during the time, well, "capture" using a call+pop trick.

But the parameter for MessageBox lpText reads the parameter as ASCII, so feeding it the value 00401005 (the captured EIP value) will turn into garbage as it tries reading it as an ASCII string.

So my idea was to take each byte using LODSB and extract each nibble of said byte and extend these into bytes so I end up with a 8 byte string. Then I would just add 48 to each value to turn them into ASCII, but i'm kind of stuck. And I was wondering if anyone knew any tricks to do this kind of extraction?

*Although far from finished, here is the code if it helps at all*

```
[BITS 32]

EXTERN _MessageBoxA@16

SECTION .text
    GLOBAL _Main

_Main:
    call _Cast

    push 0x0
    push title
    push eax
    push 0x0
    call _MessageBoxA@16

    ret 0x10

_Cast:
    mov esi, esp
    mov ecx, 8

    loop:
        xor eax, eax
        lodsb

        ; logic goes here

        dec ecx 
        jnz loop

    ret

SECTION .data

    title db "hello",0

SECTION .bss

    buffer resb 8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's stopping you from completing the code you devised?  You're loading each byte of the address into EAX.

- save the value on the stack
- process the high nibble  (mask and shift right, translate, then  display, or store)
- pop the value
- process the low nibble (mask, translate, then display, or store)
- Repeat.

One caveat is that to *translate* the nibble you can't just add 48. That would work for `0 - 9` but it would not display 'A - F` (10 through 15) correctly. So, one easy option would be a look-up table. Define a 16 byte string, and use the nibble value as the index:

```
 HEXDIGITS db "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

Then, you index into this table, for each nibble value.

If you don't mind doing a bit of labor upfront, you could generate the 256 values that correspond to `00` through `FF` and simplify your `_cast` routine by simply looking up each byte instead of each nibble. I'm not sure if this qualifies as *easier* since it's more characters to type but it would be faster since you're cutting the work for each byte of the address to a fourth (from 8 instructions to just 2).

Comment: Oh man, I didn't think of not shifting the low nibble, that was my main problem. Thanks Mike!

Comment: Good question. And I just realized that this is actually not going to work. It will display '0' to '9' ok, but fail on 'A-F'.. so, you need a different approach. I'll update the answer!